# Piping from stdin to process

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to pipe the stdin of my program to an external process using the following

```
import System.IO
import System.Posix.IO
import System.Posix.Process
import qualified System.Process as P
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, killThread)
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    h <- fdToHandle stdInput
    (Just hIn, _, _, p) <-
        P.createProcess (P.shell "runhaskell echo.hs"){ P.std_in = P.CreatePipe }

    hSetBuffering hIn NoBuffering
    tid <- forkIO $ getInput hIn
    e <- P.waitForProcess p
    killThread tid
    print e

getInput hin = do  
    forever $ do 
        l <- getLine
        hPutStrLn hin l
```

where echo.hs just echoes stdin to stdout, but if I wait a couple seconds between giving new input, I get the following error:

```
pipes.hs: <stdin>: hGetLine: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)
```

when I tried compiling with `ghc pipes.hs`, the compiled program would not redirect stdin to the stdin of echo.hs at all

Comment: Isn't *the default* for the process to inherit all three standard handles? Why are you trying to explicitly manage the transfer yourself? Do you ultimately want to change the data in transit or something?

Comment: Can you include the contents of your `echo.hs` program too? Is its functionality intended to be identical to `cat`, and for simplicity can this be reproed that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fdToHandler stdInput` call creates a new `Handle` pointing at file descriptor 0 (stdin) of the original process. After a bit of time, the garbage collector notices that it's no longer being used, and garbage collects the `Handle`, which in turn causes the underlying file descriptor to be closed. Then your `getLine` (which uses `System.IO.stdin`) call fails. That's because that `Handle` is still open, but the underlying file descriptor it's pointing at has been closed.

FWIW, I'd recommend using binary I/O on the handles to avoid issues with character encodings.